# How can i get rows id in multiple tables with jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have multiple table in Html page, I use Datatables jquery plugin.

I get rows id from a table with below code and insert it on hidden form with "AutoFill" js plugin.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#dt_basic1').DataTable({
                'columnDefs': [
                    {
                        'targets': 3,
                        'checkboxes': {
                            'selectRow': true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                'select': {
                    'style': 'multi'
                }
            });
            $('#dt_basic1 tbody').on('click',
                'tr',
                function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });
            var data = {};
            var a1 = [];
            $('#BtnClick').click(function() {
                var a = table.rows('.selected').data();
                $.each(a,
                    function (index, value) {
                        a1.push(value[4]);
                    });
                data["BreakFast"] = a1.toString();
                $("#hiddenForm").autofill(data);
                a1 = [];
                data = {};
            });
        });
```

Now i need a idea for get other table rows id separately with out duplicate code.My first table Id is "#dt_basic1".
**Code Updated :**

```
        var datasets={};
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('.register-id').DataTable({
                'columnDefs': [
                    {
                        'targets': 3,
                        'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            if (type === 'display') {
                                data = '<input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes" name="' + $('td').closest('table').attr("name") + '">';
                            }

                            return data;
                        },
                        'checkboxes': {
                            'selectRow': true,
                            'selectAllRender': '<input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes" name="' + $('td').closest('table').attr("name") + '">'
                            //'selectAllRender': '<input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes" name="'+$this.attrib("name") +'">'

                        }
                    }
                ],
                'select': {
                    'style': 'multi'
                }
            });
            $('#dt_basic1 tbody').on('click',
                'tr',
                function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

                    var catName = $('tr').closest('table').attr("name");
                    datasets[catName] = {
                        label: catName,
                        data: []
                    };
                    console.log(datasets);
                });
            var catName = "";
            $('#BtnClick').click(function() {
                var a = table.rows('.selected').data();
                $.each(a,
                    function (index, value) {
                        catName = table.name;
                        datasets[catName].data.push(value[4]);
                    });
                console.log(datasets);
                $("#hiddenForm").autofill(datasets);
                datasets = {};
            });
        });
```

Now,i can get all table data , but when i click on button that defined in jquery code all selected rows id from all tables save in 1 memory place.i need to save them in correct place by table name attribute in `datasets` object.

I need to get this result :

```
Dataset{
tbl1 : 1,2,5
tbl2 : 10,40,2
tbl3 : 2,8,7
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could ass a `register-id`class to all your tables and change your selector to :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.register-id').on('click',
            'tr',
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
        var data = {};
        var a1 = [];
        $('#BtnClick').click(function() {
            var a = table.rows('.selected').data();
            $.each(a,
                function (index, value) {
                    a1.push(value[4]);
                });
            data["BreakFast"] = a1.toString();
            $("#hiddenForm").autofill(data);
            a1 = [];
            data = {};
        });
    });
```

this will perform a foreach on tables in which onclick will be defined

**edit** :

you can access the parent id using `$(this).parent().attr('id');` you can chain it like this if needed  `$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');` then I reccommend not using autofill and push your data in your dataset with key(`$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');`) value

Comment: Thanks , but it works on a tables ... i need a way to get data separately form multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks , But why register-id ? is it default roll ?

Comment: Now , I get All id from all tables .... Where do I find out which IDs are related to which table?

Comment: you can name the class whatever you want, it's just a selector

Comment: what do you need exactly in type of data, I don't understand

Comment: Thanks for response, I was update my post may you check it ?